# Backing up a delta table to different storage location

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, delta-lake

I have source delta table which is on a container on our dev resource group like dev1@dev. I need to exactly copies these data file to another storage location on our prod cluster using prod1@prod. we have similar t delta tables on both locations. I want the prod tables have the simialr data to the one on DEV. How can I do this on Azure?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to achieve this is to use [Delta DEEP CLONE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/delta-clone) executed on Azure Databricks.  Main advantages of it are:

- it's transactional - it guarantee that either copy done, or it's failed. No partial copies, etc.
- it's incremental - when you execute it second time, it will just copy the changes since last time

The command itself could look as following:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE delta.`abfss://dev1@dev..../directory`
DEEP CLONE delta.`abfss://prod1@prod...../directory`
```

You can find more about DEEP CLONE in this [blog post](https://databricks.com/blog/2020/09/15/easily-clone-your-delta-lake-for-testing-sharing-and-ml-reproducibility.html)